# ImageIO fails to read 8x8 pixel image with "Bogus virtual array access"

Tags: java, jpeg, javax.imageio

I'm unable to read this simple 8x8 pixel gray JPEG image with ImageIO:

[image: 8x8 pixel gray image]

Minimal source code to reproduce the problem:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class ImageExceptionMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ImageIO.read(new File("image.jpg"));
    }

}
```

Output:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.imageio.IIOException: Bogus virtual array access
    at java.desktop/com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readImage(Native Method)
    at java.desktop/com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readInternal(JPEGImageReader.java:1334)
    at java.desktop/com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.read(JPEGImageReader.java:1127)
    at java.desktop/javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1470)
    at java.desktop/javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1317)
    at ImageExceptionMain.main(ImageExceptionMain.java:8)
```

This is with Java 18 on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS: `OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 18-ea+36-Ubuntu-1)`

Curiously enough, scaling the image to 16x16 pixels (but not to 4x4 pixels) in gimp avoids the exception. But how do I properly resolve the problem?

Comment: Works fine for me with OpenJDK 11 on Windows.

Comment: Works fine on [OnlineGDB](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_java_compiler) (JDK 11.0.4 Linux environment). Same code and files.

Comment: Works correctly with jdk-11.0.12.7-hotspot on Windows 10.

Comment: On Windows, your image works for me on 17u3, 18u1, 19ea27.

Comment: Works correctly with JDK17 on Windows 10.

Comment: Works for me on VirtualBox + Ubuntu 22.04 + Java 18 ea 36 ubuntu 1, running your code in JShell.

Comment: On my affected machine, I can reproduce the error on openjdk versions 17.0.3 and 11.0.15, and by running the program through javac+java, Eclipse, or JShell.

On a different machine, I cannot reproduce the problem.

Thanks for everyone who's tried to reproduce this so far. Looks like the problem is not specific to this JDK version, but dependent on some other factor of my environment. Happy to provide additional information about my system if it helps.